How to access Laravel model in Alpine.js loop?
I'm trying to go through the loop and show Laravel models, but have no idea how to access model index.
<template x-for="i in priceFields">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" :name="`prices[${i}][name]`" name="" :value="{{ $price[i]['name'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="number" :name="`prices[${i}][value]`" name="">
    </div>
</div>

The problem is a part with {{ $price[i]['name'] }}. How to insert i value?
Thanks!

You cant.
the alpine js loop runs on the client and $price is on the server. You can add the $price array to the client as json https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#rendering-json
